# Best way to get an interpolated value into a Terraform lookup

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to setup Terraform to deploy into various AWS regions, I am sending the Region on the command line since its one of the few changing values in the script.  I am using  -var "region=east" - for example, and it works in other modules by assigning the region correctly, the main.tf where I am using this value is set correctly.

In creating a resource there is a lookup which uses region as mapped value, amis is a map of regions and different ami values I only want the ami that matches for this resource.  I tried two methods, using the command line interpolation:

```
ami = "${lookup(var.amis, $${var.region})}"
```

or as an intermediate value

```
variables "map_region" {
  default = "${var.region}"
}
ami = "${lookup(var.amis, var.map_region)}"
```

Both give me syntax errors, though in looking through some of the documents with lookup I don't see where terraform supports this.  Anyone else tried this successfully in some manner, or know a better way to pull out a value from a map using a command line variable?

EDIT:
Part of the problem was hidden because I was using a Bash script to run the Terraform modules.  This was running a destroy -force, then apply.  Because I was considering the command line variables as part of the build I did not add them to the destroy command, which is where they were being requested and giving me a prompt to enter them.  Once I added in the -var commands to the destroy command as well as apply this all worked.

Comment: You'll only ever need one set of `${}` when using interpolation - anything inside of it will be rendered. I don't believe you can have interpolation inside of your variables. Does `${lookup(var.amis, 'us-east-1')}` return what you want?

Comment: Yes, it returns what I want but I need to use an interpolated value in someway so I can reuse the scripts for deploying in different regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ami = "${lookup(var.amis, $${var.region})}"
```

is wrong because `$$` is only valid for interpolated variables within [inline templates](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html#inline-templates).

```
variables "map_region" {
  default = "${var.region}"
}
ami = "${lookup(var.amis, var.map_region)}"
```

does not work because you are passing a map as a key to `lookup`.

Terraform [console](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/console.html) is a useful tool for trying out interpolated expressions. Suppose the variables are defined as follows:

```
$ cat vars.tf
variable "amis" {
  type = "map"

  default {
    "us-east-2" = "ami-58f5db3d"
    "us-east-1" = "ami-fad25980"
  }
}

variable "region" {}
```

Fire up the console passing a value to `region` to emulate what you would be doing with `plan`, `apply` etc:

```
$ terraform console -var "region=us-east-1"
> var.region
us-east-1
> lookup(var.amis, var.region)
ami-fad25980
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had tried this before, when I use the variable "region" {} in my variables file I still get a prompt for adding var.region when using apply - terraform apply -var "region=us-east-1"

Comment: Playing around with this more it looks like the bash script that is setting the variables is somehow not setting them correctly.  Using terraform apply -var region=${var_region} in Bash doesn't work, but using the command with the variable set on the command line does.  Very strange